# Why encapsulate module in function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm reading some node.js-modules in a school example app, and they are all instantiated in a function like this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    // Some declarations

    module.exports = some value;
}());
```

That is, they are all encapsulated by an anonymous function like this:

```
(function() {
    // Module
}());
```

Does anyone know what the purpose may be for doing so? Has it something to do with efficiency?

Comment: If they’re actually Node.js modules and are never used in a browser, there is no point in doing this. Node does it automatically.

Comment: ..but if it's a school example app, they might do it just to enforce the habit when you're writing browser JS.

Comment: It is a common pattern for restricting variable scope as the contents are executed immediately yet no contents leak to the global/window namespace. Definitely isn't necessary in node.js as once a module is required, the contents of the module are evaluated by default with the scope being restricted to the module.

Comment: Looks to me as if the parentheses are wrong? `(function() { ... })();`

Comment: @Arg0n [Both do the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194964/immediately-invoked-function-expression-where-to-put-the-parenthesis). Your version is more common.

Comment: @JJJ So the parentheses surrounding the `function` is not needed? `function() { ... }();`

Comment: @Arg0n What? The code in the question has parentheses around the function.

Comment: @JJJ Yeah, I was just curious. Seems it does not work tho.

Comment: @Arg0n It does work!

Comment: @Jesper Yeah, but not without parentheses surrounding function. `(function() { console.log('test') }()); //Works`, `function() { console.log('test') }(); //Error`